# Bootstrap indentation issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

This is my html code. As you could see I m using bootstrap classes. I m not able to make the question text area to be on the same alignment with the choices textarea. Any help please?

```
<div class='form-group'>
       <label class = 'col-sm-2 control-label' for = 'qn_text_1'>Question 1: </label>
       <div class = 'col-sm-8'>
           <textarea readonly class = 'form-control' id= 'qn_text_1' rows="3">Textarea for question 1</textarea>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'form-group'>
        <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for = "answerChoices_1"> Choose the correct answer(s) from the options below:
        </label>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
                <ul class = "col-sm-8" style = "list-style-type: none" id = "answerChoices_1">
                    <li>
                        <textarea class = "form-control" id = "answer_0_1" readonly>Choice 1</textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <textarea class = "form-control" id = "answer_0_2" readonly>Choice 2</textarea>
                    </li>                       
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried making few changes to the classes but no luck. any help in fixing this would be really helpful.

Thanks
SamT

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the "choices" textareas are wrapped in a div with the "row" class, while the "question" textarea is not. The row class in bootstrap has a margin-left of -15px which is causing the mis-alignment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have an indent is because of your ul and li tags.
You have 2 options to resolve this:

1) remove the ul and li tags as in this case: (there are many ways to do this) I have listed one:
https://jsfiddle.net/nepaw00c/2/

```
<div class='form-group'>
   <label class = 'col-sm-2 control-label' for = 'qn_text_1'>Question 1: </label>
   <div class = 'col-sm-8'>
       <textarea readonly class = 'form-control' id= 'qn_text_1' rows="3">Textarea for question 1</textarea>
   </div>
</div>
<div class = 'form-group'>
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for = "answerChoices_1"> Choose the correct answer(s) from the options below:
    </label>
        <div class = "col-sm-8" style = "list-style-type: none" id = "answerChoices_1">
              <div>
               <textarea class = "form-control" id = "answer_0_1" readonly>Choice 1</textarea>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <textarea class = "form-control" id = "answer_0_2" readonly>Choice 2</textarea>                 
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2) change the css of your ul and li to set the margin and padding.

Comment: To change the CSS of the ul and li tags, I would advise associating it with a class or id of your coice and setting the css of the class or id to override parent ul and li class css. That way you will not cause changes in ul and lis throughout your project